# Gatsby Blog with Contentful CMS, how to sort blog posts by date

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, contentful

My query looks like this(i have left some variables out):

```
allContentfulBlog(
      filter: { node_locale: { eq: "en-US" } }
      sort: { fields: [node___date], order: DESC }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          date(formatString: "DD MMMM, YYYY")                            
        }
      }
    }
```

Terminal error:

> GraphQL Error Argument "sort" has invalid value {fields:
>   [node___date], order: DESC}. In field "fields": In element #0:
>   Expected type "ContentfulBlogConnectionSortByFieldsEnum", found
>   node___date.

For sorting this i tried all arguments i saw in tutorials or could think of. I think its something regarding Contentful and it's data format that goes into my gatsby app.

Terminal screenshot

[image: terminal screenshot]
Browser screenshot

[image: browser output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This did the trick:

sort: { fields: [date], order: DESC }

I found it in a [Gatsby-Contentful-Starter](https://github.com/contentful-userland/gatsby-contentful-starter); I had the false impression the syntax needs to be something like fieldName___argumentByWichToSort

Comment: For figuring out the right queries I can highly recommend the included GraphiQL interface. :) With this you have a powerful autocompletion at hand.

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-five/#introducing-graphiql

Comment: @stefanjudis GraphiQL doesn't work with arguments like filter or sort, nor suggests them when you press Ctrl + Enter